# HTML Code to PNG with Phantom.js

Tags: phantomjs

Is there a way to give Phantom.js HTML code instead of a URL to render?

HTML URL Example

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Desired HTML markup example

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('<html><head><style>SOME CSS</style></head><body><div>SOME TEXT AND IMAGES</div></body></html>',
    function() {
        page.render('github.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way of doing this:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 800, height : 600 };
page.content = '<html><head><style>SOME CSS</style></head><body><div>SOME TEXT AND IMAGES</div></body></html>';

page.evaluate(function() {
    // your logic here
});

page.render('github.png');

phantom.exit();
```